# ScrollView not scrolling far enough - java Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I am working on a app where the user actions add LinearLayout's to the pre-existing LinearLayout @+id/linLayout. Sometimes these additional layouts will go off the bottom of the screen so I have put the main LinearLayout within a ScrollView. When my app starts to go off the bottom of the screen it is able to scroll a little bit but not far enough to see everything. At a certain point it is not possible to continue because a Button is off screen and cannot be pressed. Can anybody tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <Button android:id="@+id/bGenerateExample"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/generate_example" />

        <ScrollView
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:id="@+id/linLayout"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:orientation="vertical" >
            </LinearLayout>

        </ScrollView>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: are you adding any view in linear layout??  and you can give scroll view to whole page also

Comment: I'm adding LinearLayouts to the LinearLayout in the ScrollView as mentioned with the id. The ScrollView can use the whole page apart from the action bar at the top and the space where the button lives.

Comment: You're ScrollView height is wrap_content and linLayout height is fill_parent. They don't know how big to be.

Answer (score 1):

What about using weight_Sum?

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android_weight_sum=5 >
    <Button android:id="@+id/bGenerateExample"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="@string/generate_example" />

    <ScrollView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="4">

        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
            android:id="@+id/linLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="marth_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >
        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

now button covers %20 percent of screen and scrollView covers %80.You can change it easily with changing layout_weight values of scrollView, Button.

Comment: You can also set the button height to wrap_content and give the ScrollView a weight of 1. This will let the ScrollView fill the space left by the button

Comment: Thanks for the help guys. Trying this out made me realise that the problem was in activity_main.xml which had its height set to wrap_content. My xml above was included by that layout and the result was I had a margin at the bottom of the screen hiding some of my scrollview. Once I fixed that it works perfect. Dunno why someone down voted the question as soon as I posted it. I always try to be as clear as possible.

Comment: I voted up and that negative vote of someone went away because I had almost the same problem but the difference was that in my case <ScrollView> was the topmost parent and I could not scroll down to some of views. By changing the layout_width and height of the SrollView from wrap content to match parent it worked fine and I could scroll down to the bottom of the activity! thanks!